# Do you know of a good event management software?

Tags: events, registration, payment-gateway, credit-card

I'm creating a website for an event. We require storage of attendee's email-address, approval to sign-up to newsletter(s) and first & last name.

Credit card information needs to be sent somehow (PayPal? and EGold?) with payment approval noted in our database.

Confirmation emails need to be sent after sign-up (including receipt), also 2 reminder emails need to be sent; the month before and week before the event.

Which event management software project (Django-based?) should I use for this website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using Drupal with COD.